# How to write an SQL statement for two variables, one carrying the table name, and the other the specific column in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

> $select = $_POST['select'];
>       $search = $_POST['search'];
>       $sql = "SELECT * FROM '$select' WHERE $select = '$search'";

I have 2 variables carrying the aforementioned table name and column name. I want the user to be able to select a table name and then select a specific column and output the requested record.

I only have a problem with writing the sql statement. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use the following query without any problem...

`$sql="SELECT * from $select WHERE field_name='$search' ";`

In the above query field_name is the that field name in which you want to search value of mattch the value.

Answer (score 1):

you are using table instead of column

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM '$select' WHERE $select = '$search'";
                                      ^^^^^^----//this should be column not table
```

this is bad idea you are doing. FULL of sql injection

- switch to pdo or mysqli.
- Escape your variables.